# MySQL Left Join Not showing

Tags: mysql

```
select e.MAT from historico as e
right join alunos as a
on e.MAT = a.MAT
```

AND I JUST GIVES ME THE FIRST COLUMN "historico", am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You're only selecting one column. Try `SELECT *` or `SELECT e.MAT, a.MAT, a.NAME`

Comment: Man, Thank you!!! How I couldn't notice that haha

Comment: Do you know how can I separate a column just to average? I have a class with grades and I want to separate an unique column to the class average but when I do it, it turns into an unique row with the average. Is there any problem doing a different question through comments? I'm new over here, and srry about my english

Comment: @KaioPatrick Open up a new question, and we can answer that

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM historico e
RIGHT JOIN alunos a ON e.MAT = a.MAT
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to questions which are just simple typos. Instead, make a comment (as I have already done) and flag the question as "off-topic" due to a non-reproducible or typographical error. Questions like this add no value to the site and will eventually be deleted, thus causing you to lose any reputation that you may gain from answering. See [Should one advise on off topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232)

Comment: Is that a typo, or did OP not understand what `SELECT *` does? I don't think that is fair to assume.

Comment: I think OP's comment in response to mine makes it pretty clear it's a typo.